# Rails Conditional Naming

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a _form partial which rails automatically names the submit buttons for me, for new and edit views. In the new view I prefer for the submit button value to simply read "Create" instead of "Create Link"

I achieved this with `<%= form.submit "Create" %>`

How would I make rails display `<%= form.submit "Update" %>` in the edit view and `<%= form.submit "Create" %>` in the new, pending which view '_form.html.erb' is being rendered in? Thanks

_form https://gist.github.com/1293210

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I'm assuming you pass in an object, like `@user` for instance. In that case, within your _form, do this:

```
<% editing = @user.new_record? ? false : true %>
<% default_text = editing ? "Update" : "Create" %>
<% form.submit default_text %>
```

I made separate editing and default_text variables here but you could do it in one line like:

```
<% form.submit @user.new_record? ? "Create" : "Update" %>
```

The only reason why I showed you the variables is because it's easily scalable to other text you have on your form.

**Edit** I should also mention that the point of using `new_record?` works if for a new User (for example) you simply set @user to be User.new in your controller, but for editing you do User.find(...).

Comment: Thanks, I used @link.new_record? instead of user.

Comment: You're welcome. Usually I just use @user as my go-to example heh.

Comment: Yea it's my first iteration, so I haven't created users yet